(NOBRIDGE) expo-media-library: ERROR Error in creating album or adding asset: [Error: Could not get the file's extension - it was empty.]
I am using expo-media-library to access gallery. When I want to save the image I got it from the gallery (example uri ph://....) to an new album within the gallery, I am getting an error. I am doing based on Expo Documentation, but still is not working. Can somebody please check my code. What did I do wrong?
ps: One of the example imageUri I passed: ph://8D2D94AD-07E6-4237-BDEB-3DE4AB40253...
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

const createAlbumAndAddImage = async (imageUri) => {
  try {
    // Request media library permissions
    const { status } = await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      console.error('Media library permissions not granted');
      return;
    }

    // Convert `ph://` or any URI to a media library asset
    const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(imageUri);
    console.log('Created Asset:', asset);

    // Album name
    const albumName = 'Keep Or Del';

    // Check if the album exists
    const albums = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync();
    let album = albums.find((a) => a.title === albumName);

    // If the album does not exist, create it
    if (!album) {
      album = await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync(albumName, asset, false); // false means no notifications
      console.log(`Album "${albumName}" created successfully.`);
    } else {
      // If album exists, add the asset to the album
      await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album.id, false);
      console.log(`Asset added to album "${albumName}"`);
    }

    // Verify the asset is in the album
    const albumAssets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({
      album: album.id,
      first: 100, // Fetch up to 100 assets
    });
    console.log('Assets in Album:', albumAssets.assets.map((a) => a.uri));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in creating album or adding asset:', error);
  }
};

export default createAlbumAndAddImage;


